# Python Irrefutable pattern in match-case statement

Tags: python

I am getting errors that MENU_EXIT cannot be accessed and there is a irrefutable pattern. I have tried using variables and constants in for the cases but get the same errors. I am new to python (experienced c++) so not sure what the errors mean.

```
MENU_EXIT = 1
MENU_SET_AZ = 2
MENU_SET_EL = 3
MENU_GET_AZ_EL = 4
MENU_GET_AZ_EL_TLE = 5

menuOptions = ["Exit", "Set Azimuth", "Set Elevation", "Get Current Az/El"]
TLEOptions = ["TLE Epoch Time", "Propagate to Now", "Generate 24 Hours of Az/El Angles"]

def printMenu():
    print("\n---------- M-SAT Ground Station Testing Interface ----------\n")
    i = 1
    for option in menuOptions:
        output = str(i) + ". " + option
        print(output)
        i += 1
    
def menu(option):
    match option:
        case MENU_EXIT:
            print("Something is wrong if you are reading this")
            return 
        case MENU_SET_AZ:
            print("Setting Azimuth")
            return 
        case MENU_SET_EL:
            print("Setting Elevation")
            return 
        case MENU_GET_AZ_EL:
            print("Getting Az/El")
            return 
        case _: 
            print("Please enter a valid menu option")     
    
#Testing Menu 
while(True):
    printMenu()
    opt = int(input("Menu Option:"))
    if opt == 1:
        break
    menu(opt)
```

EDIT: Putting the menu options into classes solves the issue

```
class menuOpts:
    SET_AZ = 2
    SET_EL = 3
    GET_AZ_EL = 4

menuOptions = ["Exit", "Set Azimuth", "Set Elevation", "Get Current Az/El"]
TLEOptions = ["TLE Epoch Time", "Propagate to Now", "Generate 24 Hours of Az/El Angles"]

def printMenu():
    print("\n---------- M-SAT Ground Station Testing Interface ----------\n")
    i = 1
    for option in menuOptions:
        output = str(i) + ". " + option
        print(output)
        i += 1
    
def menu(option):
    match option:
        case menuOpts.SET_AZ:
            print("Setting Azimuth")
            return 
        case menuOpts.SET_EL:
            print("Setting Elevation")
            return 
        case menuOpts.GET_AZ_EL:
            print("Getting Az/El")
            return 
        case _: 
            print("Please enter a valid menu option")     
    
#Testing Menu 
while(True):
    printMenu()
    opt = int(input("Menu Option:"))
    if opt == 1:
        break
    menu(opt)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but putting the menu constants into a class then referencing the class solved the issue.

Comment: Read the linked duplicate. It is important to understand that pattern matching is not a simple switch statement (Python rejected adding such a construct several times)

Comment: In your case, you can just use and `if ... elif...else`

Comment: This looks like the job for a `dict` (or even just a `list`, seeing how the keys are consecutive numbers). A `match` is a waste for this.